# Modifying the bits of a char according to a vector<bool>

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, byte, bit

I have a vector which contains a lot of bools. When I get to 1 in the vector, I start reading the next 8 values as bits - and I want to modify a char according to those 8 values.

Example:

I have a char c = 0; (00000000).

My 8 bits according to the vector are (10101010).

How do I go around assigning these values into the bits of a char? Can I use the vector as a mask? If so, how?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `vector<bool>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bit shift operator `<<`. It shifts bits by a certain amount.

For example, `5 << 2` is `20`, because 101 shifted left by two is 10100, or twenty.

```
vector<bool> v; // plus initialization

char c;   
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {     
    c += v[i] << (v.size() - i - 1);
}
```

This assumes you want this big endian (most signitficant bit first). If you want little endian, change `(v.size() - i - 1)` to `i`.